# i am using laravel excel how i can calculate the sum of all the use total hours and show them in excel file

Tags: laravel

i have a situation where i have to find the total hours of user based on the month and i want to show it in to my excel file .
i am using laravel excel can anyone guide me how i can achieve this

```
public function collection()
    {


        return DB::table('attandancesheets')->select('code','employee','start_time','end_time',
        'ispresent',DB::raw("DAYNAME(date) as day"),'isweekend','total_hours','date',
       )->orderBy('date','asc')->get();
        
    }
```

this is how i am exporting my table data in to the excel file but i want to calcualte the total hour of each user as well how i can achieve this ?? any one can help me ?

Comment: Not an answer, but I would rename the table name to attendance_sheets because it contains a typo and it consists of two words, so a separator is helpful as per convention. Having such typos always bites you in the back in the future making you spend hours debugging a silly little typo, so try leaving no room for it when possible. And don't forget to change the class name and the file name as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well I realized you are not summing up the hours

```
public function collection()
{


    return DB::table('attandancesheets')->select(DB:raw(SUM('total_hours') as total_hours,'code','employee','start_time','end_time',
    'ispresent',DAYNAME(date) as day,'isweekend','date',
   )->orderBy('date','asc')->get();
    
}
```